# Using .NET 2.0, how do I FTP to a server, get a file, and delete the file?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, ftp

Does .NET (C#) have built in libraries for FTP? I don't need anything crazy... very simple.

I need to:

1. FTP into an account
2. Detect if the connection was refused
3. Obtain a text file
4. Delete the text file

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: It's not addressing your need, but consider that FTP is an unencrypted protocol. If you have the ability to recommend a change in requirements, you may want to push for an encrypted protocol.

Comment: FTP can be wrapped in any encrypted channel, and FTP itself supports encryption. What is an "encrypted protocol"?

Comment: Authentication data is passed in the clear -- sure you can wrap it -- and that's a great solution. I suppose I should have said that it is a not a protocol built with encryption in mind. But it seemed obvious... I've just seen too many people assume that FTP "passwords" are enough.

Comment: FTP can be run over the TLS/SSL encrypted channel too. It's often called FTPS or FTP/SSL. Relation between FTP and FTPS is similar to relation between HTTP and HTTPS. There is also another alternative - SFTP (which is SSH File Transfer Protocol).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class, or the plain old [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

FTP into an account and retrieve a file:

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
request.Credentials = 
    new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com");
try 
{
    // serverUri here uses the FTP scheme ("ftp://").
    byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(serverUri.ToString());
    string fileString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // Detect and handle login failures etc here
}
```

Delete the file:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}", response.StatusDescription);  
response.Close();
```

(Code examples are from MSDN.)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/desktopapplications/article.php/c13163) implements a GUI for an FTP client using .NET 2.0 and has full source with examples.

Sample code includes connection, download and upload as well as good comments and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class. It already handles all the things you require.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`System.Net.FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)/[`FtpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [edtFTPnet](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html), a free, open source .NET FTP library that will do everything you need.